# Paring json string in java with javax.json

Tags: java, json

My ajax passed a json array that looks like this:

```
 {"formData":[{"cusID":"2"},{"empID":"1"}],"invoice":578416969}
```

I am trying to get the data using `javax.json` library.

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jasonString);
```

I am able to grab the value of `invoice`:

```
Integer invoiceNum = (Integer) jsonObj.get("invoice");
```

But I am unable to grab the value of `cusID` and `empID`, by doing the following:

```
Integer cusId = Integer.parseInt((String) jsonObj.get("cusID"));
Integer empId = Integer.parseInt((String) jsonObj.get("empID"));
```

> Error message:org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["cusID"] not found.

What did I do wrong? I am open to suggestions,if you have a better way of handling this `json` data, I am willing to use it.

Comment: Whats the error message or result?? FYI, I am suspecting that this may have to do with how your casting your variables...

Comment: @ryekayo updated the OP added error message

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wbq4wbd2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cusID` is actually an attribute of the first object in the array `formData`:

```
jsonObj.getJsonArray("formData").getJsonObject(0).get("cusID");
```

should do the trick.

Comment: formData is a array of objects

Comment: Just edited my answer. Did not test it but this should work.

Comment: worked now. Thanks. You are missing a `;` in your code btw.

Comment: Just added it to make it perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get formData as an array, after that get the first element and get custId, after that get the second element and get empID.

Answer (score 0):

You can using Gson() library. (com.google.gson.Gson)
It makes you simple.

```
 JsonArray formData = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().get("formData").getAsJsonArray();
 Integer cusId = formData.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("cusID").getAsInt();
 Integer empId = formData.get(1).getAsJsonObject().get("empID").getAsInt();
```